# How do I take a "projector output" photo, showing the beam from my car's headlights?

Tags: lens, night, darkness, cars

Auto enthusiasts have a thing called a "Projector Output" photo, and its samples are something like this: mostly lights of the cars on a wall at night:

And here is a sample shot I did:

[image]

At full resolution, the line gets terrible. **How can I improve this?** 
And I have a

```
 18-135 lens, F/3.5-5.6
```

What are some settings and techniques you suggest to take these pictures so they won't turn blurry and be sharp ?

Comment: Maybe I'm not familiar with some expert terminology (i.e. `Projector Output`), but it's not clear to me what your question is. Could you please clarify it with an edit? Do you want to photograph the image projected on a wall by a projector?

Comment: @BartArondson yes exactly!  I want to photograph the image projected on a wall by a projector .. in my case it is lights of my car of the wall

Comment: Ok. But now I wonder what it is that you want to improve. The first photo for example looks ok to me. Do you maybe have a sample image (from the internet) that shows how you want it to look?

Comment: @BartArondson Thanks, I found one of my own shots for a sample, updated the question with its picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> At full resolution, the line gets terrible.

Perhaps I've missed something, but it sounds like you want to make the line between the light and dark parts of the wall as sharp as possible, more like the lights on the right hand side of [this image](http://www.autocityimports.com/blog/2011/2008-lancer-evo-x-projector-headlights/) than the ones on the left:

[image: headlights]

In that case, as long as your camera is properly focussed in the first place, the real issue is not the camera but the lights. The sharpness of the top edge of the headlight beams is due to the geometry of the lights (size of light source, shape of reflector, lens arrangement, position of any baffles). Again, if I understand the question, you're really asking about headlights rather than photography. Check [this reddit page](http://www.reddit.com/r/cars/comments/1nih24/a_guide_to_hidxenon_lighting_systems_and_why/) for some information about projectors in headlights.

In your comment below, you asked about taking a photo where the dark portions of the image still have visible detail, as in the image above. To achieve that, you'll need to change the balance of light. There's not much you can do to change the brightness of the headlights, but you can make them seem less intense by using a faster shutter speed, or a smaller aperture, or by decreasing the camera's sensitivity (lower ISO setting). That will help bring out some of the detail in the light parts of the image rather than having those parts be completely washed out. Once you've got that setting, you'll need to add more light to the rest of the image to make details in the dark areas visible. You can do that by just turning on the lights in the garage. If you have a set of [work lights](http://www.staples.com/office/supplies/StaplesProductDisplay?storeId=10001&catalogIdentifier=2&partNumber=WYF078276353102&langid=-1&cid=PS:GooglePLAs:WYF078276353102&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=WYF078276353102&KPID=WYF078276353102&kpid=WYF078276353102&gclid=CMLTkf6K0MICFSxk7AodpDoA5A) handy, you could use them if you need more light. You can also use one or more speedlights if you have them, but the built-in flash that some cameras have might not be enough to compete with the headlights. You could also use daylight -- point the car at the back wall of the garage and open the garage door as much as necessary to provide the level of ambient light that you want.

Comment: great picture you posted, so in your picture we can see all the other stuff in the garage too, but my problem is that for me everything else is dark. I want a setting that can show the rest of the stuff in the garage too like your photo

Comment: That's just an image I found on [this page](http://www.autocityimports.com/blog/2011/2008-lancer-evo-x-projector-headlights/), not one I took myself. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. I've added a link to the source page in the text above. I'll also add some advice for getting the result you want.

Answer (score 3):

Put your camera on a tripod, focus manually on the wall, and set aperture (probably a higher number, like f/11 to get deep DoF) and time manually, too. This way, you'll get consistent results over multiple shots.

Comment: how long of time? like 1.6 seconds? or longer? Also what ISO range to try? maybe 100?

Comment: So that you get a good exposure. That really depends on your scene. The rule for ISO is: "as low as possible". If you have no moving scene, and thus can expose as long as you want, this is the base ISO of your camera, probably 100.

Comment: And if the shutter speed is between about 1/100 second and 1 second also use mirror lockup and a wired shutter release if your camera offers these features.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you were using a flash and a high speed shutter because it appears you caught the shutter in motion (thus the large black wall).

To get a well focused shot, if possible, pre-focus with the light on.  Focus has a hard time operating in the dark, so providing extra light is the easiest way to allow it to focus and then remove the light before the exposure.  (Be sure to move in to manual focus after the pre-focus to prevent changes after setting it.)

If more light for focusing isn't an option, then you are left to guess and check a bit with manual focus.  If there is a spot focus feature on the LCD (where it digitally zooms in to let you focus using the LCD) you can use that feature as well to help out, but in high levels of darkness, it can still be tricky.

You will also want to use a tripod to avoid motion blur, particularly when using longer shutter speeds.

Comment: so you suggest to first with garage lights on, do focus on the Wall and use Auto Focus Lock feature to lock the focus, then turn off the lights and take the shot?

Comment: @user1899082 - that'd be the easiest way.  More light = easier focus and focus won't change as long as the camera (and the subject) doesn't move.

Answer (score 3):

To get shadows with sharp edges, you need hard light.
The smaller and the further away a light source is, the "harder" is its light.
The sun is a good example for that.

Technically, the rays of hard light are close to being parallel.

No matter how hard the light is, the edge of the shadow can still be blurry.
This is because there's a distance between the wall and whatever casts the shadow.
Reduce this  distance to a minimum.

Examples:
Go outside on a cloud day. the light is soft, you will not cast a shadow with a sharp edge.
Go outside in full sun. You cast a shadow with a sharp edge. The sharpness of the edge will vary. The edge of the shadow cast from your head will be more blurry than the shadow that's cast from your legs, because your legs are closer to the surface that the shadow is cast on (the ground) than your head.